# Angular - does not update data rendered by template from ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-include directive:

```
<div ng-include="'row_renderer.html'" onload="subItem=item"></div>
```

It renders properly but what I want to achieve is to pass "item" as "subItem" variable. What I did does the trick but when the scope gets updated it won't update the data loaded by ng-include with onload directives.

Bigger part of my code:

```
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="list.results">
            <li ng-repeat="item in list.results | filter:filterByPlaceGroup | filter:filterBySubmission track by $index" ui-tree-node class="root-element" ng-class="{collapsed_root: collapsed_items[item.id]}">
                <form name="submissionForm" >
                    {% verbatim %}
                    <div ui-tree-handle class="header" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px" ng-class="{collapsed_header: collapsed_items[item.id]}">
                        <div ng-include="'row_renderer.html'" onload="subItem=item"></div>
                    </div>
                    {% endverbatim %}
                </form>
            </li>
        </ol>
```